# C# Unity3D - Get stuck with an sticky situation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game inside Unity3D but im stuck with something what I try to find the solution on it.

Its a part of a stock system where you can store things in it like "items or materials".

---

**the following variables / classes are as follows :**

```
[Serializable] public class ItemStorage
{
    public ExtendedList.Items item;
    public List<MaterialStorage> material;

}

[Serializable] public class MaterialStorage
{
    public ExtendedList.Ingots material;
    public int materialCount;
}
```

Above are the classes.

---

```
public List<ItemStorage> itemstorage; 
public List<MaterialStorage> materialstorage;
```

Above are the variables.

---

**and under this are the enums what i bassicly use :**

```
   public enum Items : int
   {
        [Description("Helmet")]
        HELMET = 0,
        [Description("Chestplate")]
        CHESTPLATE = 4,
        [Description("Platelegs")]
        PLATELEGS = 8,
        [Description("Gaunlets")]
        GAUNLETS = 12,
        [Description("Boots")]
        BOOTS = 16,
        [Description("Sword")]
        SWORD = 20,
        [Description("Shield")]
        SHIELD = 24,
        [Description("Wheel")]
        WHEEL = 28,
        [Description("Axe")]
        AXE = 32
    }

    public enum Ingots : int
    {
        [Description("Bronze Ingot")]
        BRONZE = 0,
        [Description("Iron Ingot")]
        IRON = 5,
        [Description("Steel Ingot")]
        STEEL = 10,
        [Description("Silver Ingot")]
        SILVER = 15,
        [Description("Platinum Ingot")]
        PLATINUM = 20
    }
```

---

**but I have a code where I call it in the "Awake" to initialize the / those list(s) :**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExtendedList.Ingots)).Length; i++)
    {
        if (GameManager.Instance.PlayerLevel >= ExtendedList.GetIngotValue(i))
        {
            materialstorage.Add(new MaterialStorage() { material = (ExtendedList.Ingots)ExtendedList.GetIngotValue(i) });
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetNames(typeof(ExtendedList.Items)).Length; i++)
    {
        if (GameManager.Instance.PlayerLevel >= ExtendedList.GetItemValue(i))
        {
            itemstorage.Add(new ItemStorage() { item = (ExtendedList.Items)ExtendedList.GetItemValue(i), material = materialstorage });
        }
    }
```

---

On start it initializes as perfect. So at **material list** i get (bronze) and in the **item list** I get (helmet) but when I level up I call the function. So in the **material list** i get (bronze, bronze) and in the **item list** I get (helmet, helmet) instead of (bronze) and (helmet).\

---

**edit :
(forgot) : when the player is level 0 it only initializes bronze. but when it reaches level 5 its adding a new list. 
but than instead of bronze its iron.
so i want to add a new list when the player level is equalls to the value what i give to iron, steel, silver, platinum, etc.**

---

I hope you guys can help me with this sticky situation.

Best wishes, And have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem with ur method **(Sasang)**

the the console is giving now the correct key / values.

in the for loop is everything the same except the line with calculating the value line.

the code looks right now like this :

```
ExtendedList.Ingots value = (ExtendedList.Ingots)Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExtendedList.Ingots)).GetValue(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I was slightly mistaken in how the dictionary was being populated, the reason you are seeing "1","2" is because of the values being inserted into the dictionary, not the key. Take this line you have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExtendedList.Ingots)).Length; i++)
```

The variable **i** will loop from 0 -> 4, because you have 5 elements in ExtendedList.Ingots. That means that when the following bit of code is run:

```
int key = ExtendedList.GetLevel((ExtendedList.Ingots)i);
ExtendedList.Ingots value = (ExtendedList.Ingots)i;
levelToMaterialsMap.Add(key, value);
```

The variable **value** will only ever be **BRONZE,1,2,3,4**. This is because when you cast an integer to an enum as in the second line above, even if it doesn't find the value in your Enum set, the cast will still work but **value** will now equal to **i** , that's just how enums works in .NET. So in the first loop, the cast is (ExtendedList.Ingots)(0) -> BRONZE because it found the value 0 in the enum set. From the second  iteration onward, it doesn't find the value so you get (ExtendedList.Ingots)(1) -> 1, (ExtendedList.Ingots)(2) -> 2 and so on.

Comment: i see. but when i debug like this : **Debug.Log(levelToMaterialsMap[5]);**

output ---> "1", instead of "iron", but when i do :

**Debug.Log(levelToMaterialsMap[0]);**

output ---> "BRONZE"

Comment: sometimes C# is weird. or im just dumb. maybe its just my dumbiness ;)

Comment: No i think i know whats going on. What does the method ExtendedList.GetLevel() look like?

Comment: The ExtendedList.GetLevel() looks like this ----> **public static int GetLevel(this Items item)
        {
            return (int)item;
        }**

Comment: i still get the same output.

Comment: but thx for putting ur time to help me but i dont know how we can fix this issue effeciently tho.

Comment: I didnt suggest a change, i'm just saying thats the reason you are getting the error. You have to change your for loop to only fetch the keys of the level 0,5,10,15,20 instead of iterating from 0-4

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting [bronze, bronze] at level2 in your materialstorage list (instead of just [bronze]) is because you are adding values to your list with **materialstorage.Add**, it seems to me that what you really want is to initialize a new list every time that method runs, so before you iterate through your enums in the for loops, set the materialstorage and itemstorage to new lists.

Also i dont entirely understand the reason for having materialstorage list defined twice if they always appear to be the same value. You have it defined at the gamemanager level and also again in each itemStorage object. If i understand your edit statement correctly, i seems like you want a list of lists where the number of lists is equal to the number of level increments like so:

```
0:  [[bronze]]
5:  [[bronze], [bronze,iron]]
10: [[bronze], [bronze,iron], [bronze,iron,steel]]
...
```

In this case what you really need is a Dictionary, one which maps player level to a separate list of materials. You can initialize this at the in your main GameManager class. Where the number of keys in the dictionary equals to the number of elements in your enum, like so:

```
 Dictionary<int, List<MaterialStorage>> levelToMaterialsMap =
            new Dictionary<int, List<MaterialStorage>>();
 for (int i = 0; i < Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExtendedList.Ingots)).Length; i++)
    {
        int key = ExtendedList.GetIngotValue(i);
        List<MaterialStorage> value = new List<MaterialStorage>();
        levelToMaterialsMap.add(key, value);
    }
```

Now every time you call your looping method, check to see if the player level is one of the levels in which you need to add materials for, if it is then create a new materialstorage list, add all the materials to it, then set it into the Dictionary for that specific level key. Something like:

```
if(levelToMaterialMap.containsKey(GameManager.Instance.PlayerLevel))
{
   List<MaterialStorage> materialstorage = new List<MaterialStorage>();
   //Do all the stuff you need to add materials for this player level
   //...
   //Then
   levelToMaterialMap[GameManager.Instance.PlayerLevel] = materialstorage;
}
```

Comment: in the for loop with in the line where **int value = new List<MaterialStorage>();** there is an error or typed it wrong.

can i ask what should stay there or could you edit it?


And thank you for helping me in this good way ^^

Comment: sorry was a typo, it should be List<MaterialStorage>, edited it